# How do I put a delete link within an update form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a remote form for updating a 'Point' model. It's a pretty ordinary form with a submit button.

However, I'd like to also include a 'remove' button beside the 'update' button.

Unfortunately, there is a problem with this. When I click on the 'update' button it ends up deleting the entry - the delete link seems to hijack the update form.

EDIT: I think I know why the update button is deleting. When I add the delete link to the form it adds this input:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">
```

Regardless of whichever button I press this "_method" param is being picked up!

Now, I know that I can just position the remove button outwith the form element but in this case I'm not allowed to.

I guess the remove button could just be another update submit button, but with an extra :remove_this parameter.

However, something about that doesn't feel right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another curious workaround that does not require javascript, is to put the delete-form outside the update-form but leave a <label **for="theSubmitButtonInTheDeleteForm"**> inside the update form.
The update-form will continue to work as expected, but clicking the label will submit the delete-form.
Then just style the label as a button.

Comment: That smacks of a certain evil genius!  Clever solution to an old problem - I think I'm going to try this one.

Comment: One note to add to this solution: The real form button the label points to must not be set to display: none.  The solution doesn't work in some versions of IE if the button isn't rendered.  A working alternative is to position the real button far off the left of the page.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend using a link rather than a button and style it like a button:

```
link_to("Remove", resource_url, method: :delete, class: "delete_button")
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it.

Comment: But rails doesn't create a form for this as the method is delete? Becuase this would generate a form inside a form, which is not valid

Comment: @ArnoldRoa. Using `link_to` with `method: :delete` produces a link that looks like: `<a href="/url/goes/here" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete it</a>`

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3 the recommended way to submit forms using Ajax is to use `form_for` in combination with `UJS` rather than `remote_form_for`. Please see this [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) episode for more info.

Then when the document is ready/loaded, you add a click listener to each of the buttons, and act accordingly:

```
$('#id_of_delete_button').click(function() {
  // serialize the form and submit it to the delete action
});

$('#id_of_update_button').click(function() {
  // serialize the form and submit it to the update action
});
```

The given code snippet is in jQuery, but you can use Prototype in a similar way as well.

Comment: I actually switched over to using form_for :remote => true 
Is this still obtrusive?

Comment: `form_for :remote => true` generates unobtrusive JS, but I am not sure that without custom JS it can handle multiple buttons in the same form.

Comment: I meant to say it generates unobtrusive.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the only difference between the 'update form' and a 'delete form' is the presence of `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">`

So here's the workaround I came up with:

```
<%= form.submit 'Update', :id => "point_#{point.id}_submit", :style => "" %>        
<%= form.submit 'Remove', :confirm => 'Are you sure?',  :id => "point_#{point.id}_remove" %>

remove_button.observe('click', function(event)
{       
      form_element.insert('<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">');
}
```

Comment: Really old question, but the way around this without the JS hack above is to use `submit_to` to generate the Remove button. This will generate a new HTML form on the page with the _method="delete".

Answer (score 1):

```
= f.button :submit, class: "btn-primary"
= link_to "Delete", f.object, class: 'btn btn-default', data: {method: 'DELETE'}
```

Delete link is styled with Bootstrap to look like a button. `jquery-ujs` hijacks clicks on links with `data-method` attribute and sends them with custom HTTP method.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
<%= button_to 'Delete', point_path(point), :method => 'delete', :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

Comment: Hi Mischa, this is what I've tried but what happens is the delete link seems to 'hijack' the update form - so when I click on the 'update' button it ends up deleting! Sorry should've explained the problem better.

Comment: There is no way to put the delete button outside the form?

Comment: I've got an awkward situation where I can't. For style purposes I need to have the button within a div (which has to reside inside the form). However, I can't put the form inside said div either.

Comment: Hm, in that case you could try a workaround where the delete button (which is actually a "delete form" with only a button and hidden fields) is outside the form and not visible and have a button inside the form that submit the hidden "delete form" via javascript. Not pretty, but maybe it works.

Comment: Yep that would work. 
I've realised that what I've ended up with is a form with 2 submit buttons. So there's a similar thing I could do where the 'remove' button adds the element:   

<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">     
and then submits the form.

Answer (score -1):

you would make a link_to 'del', Variable, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete

The :method => :delete will call the destroy part of your controller.

Comment: This will result in the problem this post is trying to solve. See another of the questions for explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5991349/387310